# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, decomposition, countvectorizer

I am receiving an error Index is out of bounds in my line **doctopic = clf.fit_transform(dtm)** and in my Data folder I have two CSV files and could someone explain how to fix this Index error.

```
import os
print (os.getcwd())
import numpy as np
import langdetect
from stop_words import get_stop_words
CORPUS_PATH = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\mike120\\Downloads\\TM 09-25\\Data')
filenames = sorted([os.path.join(CORPUS_PATH, fn) for fn in 
os.listdir(CORPUS_PATH)])

len(filenames)
filenames[:5]

import sklearn.feature_extraction.text as text
#lang = langdetect.detect(CORPUS_PATH)
lang_stop = get_stop_words('en')
vectorizer = text.CountVectorizer(input='filename', stop_words=lang_stop, min_df=2)
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(filenames).toarray()
vocab = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
dtm.shape

from sklearn import decomposition
num_topics = 20
num_top_words = 20
clf = decomposition.NMF(n_components=num_topics, random_state=1)

doctopic = clf.fit_transform(dtm)
```

Comment: I'm no python expert but what does the `dtm.shape` line do? Is that a mistake?

Comment: What is the dimension of the dtm array? In other words, how many items does dtm contain?

Comment: dimensions of dtm array (2, 132320)